# Specify a configuration file with FopFactoryBuilder

Tags: java, configuration, apache-fop

Originally I was creating my FopFactory like so:

```
FopFactory.newInstance(new File("config/pdf/fop.xconf"))
```

Which picked up all of the custom configuration in my configuration file. However, my requirements have changed and I need to use a FopFactoryBuilder to build my FopFactory (which does not take a configuration file as a parameter).

```
FopFactoryBuilder builder = new FopFactoryBuilder(URI.create("/"), uriResolverAdapter);
Configuration configuration = new DefaultConfiguration("config/pdf/fop.xconf");
builder.setConfiguration(configuration);
```

But, this doesn't seem to work. I specifically need to include some font related stuff:

```
<fonts>
  <auto-detect/>
  <font-base>./</font-base>
  <directory recursive="true">config/pdf/fonts</directory>
</fonts>
```

**Edit:**

I've also tried this,

```
DefaultConfigurationBuilder defaultConfigurationBuilder = new DefaultConfigurationBuilder();
builder.setConfiguration(defaultConfigurationBuilder.build("config/pdf/fop.xconf"));
```

as well as this,

```
builder.setConfiguration(defaultConfigurationBuilder.buildFromFile(new File("config/pdf/fop.xconf")));
```

this,

```
FileInputStream config = new FileInputStream(new File("config/pdf/fop.xconf"));
builder.setConfiguration(defaultConfigurationBuilder.build(config));
```

this,

```
builder.setConfiguration(defaultConfigurationBuilder.buildFromFile("config/pdf/fop.xconf"));
```

and finally this (Jars.getJarFile just gets the file of the running jar):

```
File jarFile = Jars.getJarFile(this);
if (jarFile!= null) {
    String absoluteLocation = jarFile.getParent() + "/config/pdf/fop.xconf";
    builder.setConfiguration(defaultConfigurationBuilder.buildFromFile(absoluteLocation));
}
```

but those all give me an exception when I create a new fop with FopFactory:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not absolute
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I ended up doing was creating a configuration like this:

```
DefaultConfigurationBuilder defaultConfigurationBuilder = new DefaultConfigurationBuilder();
builder.setConfiguration(defaultConfigurationBuilder.build("config/pdf/fop.xconf"));
```

and removing the following line from my configuration:

```
<auto-detect/>
```